# Rolling 52 Week High

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rolling-computation

I have a  SQL Server stocks database and am trying to calculate the rolling 52 week high and low close prices for the stocks.

When using a window function MAX() and trying to partition to the rolling 52 week periods how can I limit the partition to only the rolling 52 weeks (or 1 year time period)?

I believe what I am doing (screenshot) will produce the rolling maximum for the 365 rolling observations. But because markets are closed on weekends and holidays this may not actually be the same as the 52 weeks:

```
SELECT 
symbol, 
dates, 
[close],

MAX( [close] ) OVER(PARTITION BY symbol 
    ORDER BY dates
    ROWS BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [52_week_high]

FROM dbo.adj_daily_prices

WHERE 
dates BETWEEN CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-10-15' AS DATE)
AND
symbol = 'CLR'
AND
is_last = 1

ORDER BY
dates DESC
```

[image]

I imagine there is a clever way to do this with a CASE WHEN expression?

Comment: Please do not post image. Post your query, sample data and expected result as formatted text

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question with the code posted instead of a picture. Do you have a recommendation still on how to include the data easily, or is a screenshot OK for the data to give an idea of what it looks like?

Comment: Its quite amazing how so many technical people struggle with this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: You need to normalize your data around a Day/Month/Year scheme that supports multiple years. Query in a way that week 52 is not week 52 of the current year but perhaps week 3006 within the window of data containing the points you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not currently possible with analytic functions in Microsoft SQL Server, but it is possible in other databases. See https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/over_range_between_(datetime)

You can alternatively use a join to the same table, with the date criteria:

```
select    p.symbol, 
          p.dates, 
          p.[close],
          max(h.[close]) as [52_week_high],
          min(h.[close]) as [52_week_low]
from      adj_daily_prices  p
     join adj_daily_prices  h
       on p.symbol = h.symbol
      and h.dates between dateadd(year,-1,p.dates) and p.dates
where     p.dates between '2019-01-01' and '2021-10-15'
      and p.symbol = 'CLR'
group by  p.symbol, 
          p.dates, 
          p.[close]
order by  p.dates desc;
```

Comment: Thank you Brian. I was hoping there was a way to do this using the analytic functions. I had tried the example from that same website you shared, but I understand they were saying it wouldn't work with T-SQL. Thanks for an option that works. I think this does solve the problem though to filter to the last year with filter on h.dates.

Answer (score 1):

By 'main query' I was referring to the last-step returning your results. But in any case I now understand that you don't want the solution to be limited to 1 year, so, I believe this one is closer to what you are seeking. No CTEs or calendar tables, but just a subquery as a select column expression. Not limited to a year.

(I don't know what your **is_last** column does so I just included is_last=1 thinking that it might be marking the most recent row for each symbol & dates)

```
with
adj_daily_prices as ( -- this simulates your table
    select *
    from (values
          ('CLR', '2021-01-01', 58, 1)
        , ('CLR', '2019-04-05', 70, 1)
        , ('CLR', '2021-01-05', 56, 1)
        , ('CLR', '2021-02-15', 60, 1)
        ) T(symbol, dates, [close], is_last)
)
SELECT 
    symbol, 
    dates, 
    [close],
    (select max([close])
     from adj_daily_prices ftWkh
     where ftWkh.symbol=adp.symbol
     and is_last=1
     and ftWkh.dates between dateadd(week, -52, adp.dates) and adp.dates
     )  AS [52_week_high]
FROM 
    adj_daily_prices adp

WHERE 
    adp.dates BETWEEN CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-10-15' AS DATE)
    AND
    symbol = 'CLR'
    AND
    is_last = 1
ORDER BY
adp.dates desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the option. This didn't work for me. The Cal CTE table only produced 123 rows, not 366 rows. I'm not sure even if that worked - or if I just had a long dates table in my database - this solution would always work. It seems like it would run into trouble on leap years (365 or 366 day years)?

Comment: İt is a matter of finding a table in your database which has 366 rows or more. I can also give you an option not using an existing table by using recursion. Although having a date or calendar table in your database is useful in many ways. I'll give you the recursive option a bit later. As for leap years, the calendar table should already have 366 days, and the main query can use dateadd(week, -52... Or dateadd(year, -1.. then it is agnostic to leap years of

Comment: No need to explain how to make the dates table, I understand what you are saying. If you have a chance to explain what you mean about in the "main query" I'd appreciate any help. I was trying to doing this on a rolling basis so I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I didn't want to filter the dates to only 1 year.

Comment: I changed my answer. You might find this one addresses your question

Comment: Thank you userMT. This solution works as well to what I was trying to accomplish. I was hoping that this was going to be possible with the analytic functions MAX() OVER(), but that isn't possible with TSQL. Thank you for providing a working alternative!